# How to write even numbers from sequential access file to a new sequential access files

Tags: c++, io

Can someone with a little time on their hands please compile and run this code and see where I am going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ios;

int main()
{
    int numbers = 0;

    //create and open file
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open ("numbers.txt", ios::in);
    outFile.open ("evenNumbers.txt", ios::out);

    //determine whether the file was opened
    if (inFile.is_open() && outFile.is_open())
    {
        //read numbers file
        inFile >> numbers;

        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            //look for even numbers
            if (numbers %2 == 0)
            {
                outFile << numbers << endl;
                //cout << numbers << endl;
            }
            inFile >> numbers;

        }
        //end while

        //close files
        outFile.close();
        inFile.close();

        cout << "Program successful. File complete." << endl;

    }
    //if file fails to open, display error message
    else
        cout << " File could not be opened " << endl;

    //end if

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
} //end of main function
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has quite a few problems:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in);
```

It's not exactly an error, but `ios::in` is the default for an `ifstream`, and you typically supply the file name to the constructor, something like this:

```
ifstream inFile("numbers.txt");
```

Then we have this:

```
getline(inFile, name);
inFile >> num;
while (inFile.eof())
```

`while (inFile.eof())` seems to have the logic backwards -- you want to read *until* you reach the end of the, then quit. The rest of your loop will work (unusual for one that uses `file.eof()` as the condition) but is unnecessarily long and difficult to read.

```
 //create file object and open the file
 ofstream outFile;
 outFile.open("updatedNumbers.txt", ios::out);
```

As you'd expect from the previous comment, `ios::out` is the default for an `ofstream`, and you usually give the file name to the constructor: `ofstream outFile("updatedNumbers.txt");`

```
 //write the updated numbers to the file
 outFile << heading << endl;
 outFile << columnHeaders << endl;
 outFile << underLines << endl;
```

`heading`, `columnHeadders` and `underLines` seem to be undefined variables.

```
    for (x=0;x<20; x++)
    {
    if (int x%2==0)
      sample[x] = x+2;
    else
      sample[x] = x+20;
```

`sample` also seems to be undefined.

```
   outFile << num[x] << endl;
```

`num` also seems to be undefined. Perhaps you intended it to be the same as `sample`? Otherwise, you don't seem to have any code to set it to any particular value before you write it out.

Probably worse than any of that is the fact that your heading talks about writing the even numbers from one file to another, but your code doesn't seem to do anything even vaguely similar to that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the heading variable is undeclared, but I guess you already know that....

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
outFile << heading << endl;
outFile << columnHeaders << endl;
outFile << underLines << endl;
```

This is the first time you these variables `heading`, `columnHeaders` and `underLines` are mentioned in your program. The compiler complains because they have not been declared anywhere (Should they be `int` or `std::string` ore some other type?). Also they won't contain any useful values because nothing has been assigned to them.